# How to separate a while loop into pages using only one script?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently designing a survey-type system wherein the system displays the number of persons to be voted using a while loop. Unfortunately, I don't know how to create pages and instead, I can only iterate the whole while loop into one full-page script.

Here's my code:

```
while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query1)){

    //Code here

        while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query2)){

            //VERIFY ANSWERS
            if(isset($_POST['voted'])){
                if(in_array($_POST['score('.$fetch['questionID'].')'], $radioValue)){
                }
                else{
                    $missed++;
                }

                $checker = true;
            }
        }

            //CHECKER IF A RADIO BUTTON IS MISSED 
            if($checker==true){
                if($missed==$rows || $missed < $rows && $missed != 0 ){
                    echo "<center><font color=red>All items are required</font><br>";
                }
                else{
                    //Some code here
                }
            }

        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions");
        while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            //DISPLAYS QUESTIONS WITH QUESTION NUMBER
                            //Some code here

            //DISPLAYS RADIO BUTTONS FROM 1 to 5    
                            //Some code here
            }
        }

    echo "</table>
    <br><center>
    <input type='submit' name='voted' value='Submit'>
}
```

So basically, my code is just a while loop within a while loop

Edit: To make it clear, I'm asking how to separate while loop iterations into "pages" using only one script.

So basically, what I want to happen is:

Nominee 1
Display questions (1 to 9)

Next button

Nominee 2
Display questions (1 to 9) again

Also, it will only re-iterate depending on the number of items the fetch_array command has gathered.

Comment: erm, sorry! Was there some question in there?

Comment: Uhh what do you mean? The title says it. I'm asking how to separate while loop iterations into different pages instead of a full running page.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `LIMIT` in your SQL query, and fetch just that page question list.

Something like: `SELECT * FROM questions LIMIT 0, 10` will fetch first 10 questions.

I would recommend to read MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html and also **DO NOT** use *mysql_** php functions, they are deprecated, use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` functions

Comment: No no, it's not like that, I'm trying to re-print every question in relation with the number of items to be voted for (number of nominees).

Also, I'm using mysql_* function since I'm new to this stuff and I have already started my project with it.. No much time left to redo everything.. Sorry

Comment: In that case you should first fetch all questions and store them in an array, let's say `$questions`, then fetch all nominees and put a `foreach` loop within the nominee loop, basically, a nested loop.

Comment: So, would I disregard any while loops if I did that?

Answer (score 0):

If I've got your question, then I think you can do it like this:

```
<?php
   while(...) {
 #your while loop code
?>
your HTML code for showing data 
<?php
 } # terminate while loop 
?>
```

PHP code will come under PHP tags and HTML will come outside the PHP tags.

Comment: So.. how would this terminate while loop actually happen?

Comment: terminating curly brace,'}' will handle it. You don't need to worry about that,while loop will get terminated whenever it'll see '}'

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to:-

```
Page 1.  
 PROCESS POST FROM PREVIOUS PAGE (ie none until page 2)  
 Get nominees that need questions answered LIMIT 1.  
 IF NO RESULTS:
    SAY "thank you - all finished"  
 OTHERWISE:
    display nominee details  
    loop through questions 1-9  
    post form to this script -> this will be page 2
```

Comment: I quite don't grasp about the IF NO RESULTS part but basically, yeah, that's what I want to happen. However, the info from page 1 will nonetheless be posted into a summary page not page 2 itself. I would be doing a logic to gather all answers from every page but my real problem is how to make the pages themselves.

Comment: As the questions are answered they should no longer be counted as nominees, otherwise you'll be in an endless loop.

Comment: I see, but how would I be able to implement it that only 1 set of question is displayed per nominee?